# Not able to deserialise JSON file

Tags: c#, json.net

I have one json file that I want to de serialise with newtonsoft json library.

Please help.

#### Json file

```
[{
        "2406_1": [{
                "GSTIN_Status": "Active",
                "GSTIN": "18AABCF2533P1ZE",
                "Unique_ID": "5",
                "State": "Assam",
                "Input_PAN": "AABCF2533P",
                "Processing_Status": "Success"
            },
            {
                "GSTIN_Status": "Active",
                "GSTIN": "03AABCF2533P1ZP",
                "Unique_ID": "5",
                "State": "Punjab",
                "Input_PAN": "AABCF2533P",
                "Processing_Status": "Success"
            },
            {
                "GSTIN_Status": "Active",
                "GSTIN": "06AABCF2533P1ZJ",
                "Unique_ID": "5",
                "State": "Haryana",
                "Input_PAN": "AABCF2533P",
                "Processing_Status": "Success"
            },
            {
                "GSTIN_Status": "Active",
                "GSTIN": "23AABCF2533P1ZN",
                "Unique_ID": "5",
                "State": "Madhya Pradesh",
                "Input_PAN": "AABCF2533P",
                "Processing_Status": "Success"
            },
            {
                "GSTIN_Status": "Active",
                "GSTIN": "27AABCF2533P1ZF",
                "Unique_ID": "5",
                "State": "Maharashtra",
                "Input_PAN": "AABCF2533P",
                "Processing_Status": "Success"
            },
            {
                "GSTIN_Status": "Active",
                "GSTIN": "07AABCF2533P1ZH",
                "Unique_ID": "5",
                "State": "Delhi",
                "Input_PAN": "AABCF2533P",
                "Processing_Status": "Success"
            },
            {
                "GSTIN_Status": "Active",
                "GSTIN": "08AABCF2533P1ZF",
                "Unique_ID": "5",
                "State": "Rajasthan",
                "Input_PAN": "AABCF2533P",
                "Processing_Status": "Success"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "2406_2": [{
            "GSTIN_Status": "Active",
            "GSTIN": "27AABCF2544E1ZZ",
            "Unique_ID": "11",
            "State": "Maharashtra",
            "Input_PAN": "AABCF2544E",
            "Processing_Status": "Success"
        }]
    },
    {
        "2406_83998": [{
            "GSTIN_Status": "Active",
            "GSTIN": "29AABCF2416M1ZJ",
            "Unique_ID": "83961",
            "State": "Karnataka",
            "Input_PAN": "AABCF2416M",
            "Processing_Status": "Success"
        }]
    }
]
```

#### Code

```
    public class RootObject
{
    public List<OutputList> OutputList { get; set; }

    public RootObject()
    { }

}
 public class OutputList
{
    public string GSTIN_Status { get; set; }
    public string GSTIN { get; set; }
    public string Unique_ID { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Input_PAN { get; set; }
    public string Processing_Status { get; set; }


public OutputList()
{

}
}


OutputList Obj = new OutputList();

                string FileName = IDfileUpload.PostedFile.FileName;
                string path =Server.MapPath("~/InputFiles/"+FileName);
                string json = "";
                JavaScriptSerializer JavaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(path))
                {
                    json = r.ReadToEnd().Trim();
                }

                List<RootObject>instance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
                string GSTIN = instance[0].OutputList[0].GSTIN;
```

Comment: I am getting an array of three elements but values are null  in all of the three elements.

Comment: That kind of information belongs in the question itself, not in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements are null because your JSON doesn't match the `RootObject` class structure you've defined.

Here's a skeleton of your JSON:

```
[ // An array
    { // An object
        "2406_1": // A name
        [         // A value (another array)
            { // Another object
                "GSTIN_Status": "Active", // More name-value pairs
                ...
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    {
        "2406_2": [
            {
                "GSTIN_Status": "Active",
                ...
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "2406_83998": [
            {
                "GSTIN_Status": "Active",
                ...
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

In short, your JSON is an *array* of *objects*, where an *object* consists of *name-value pairs*. In this case it looks like each of those objects consists of exactly one name-value pair, where the name appears to be a unique key of some sort and the value is an array of `OutputList`.

How do you represent something in C# that maps a unique string-based key to an array of `OutputList`? Using `Dictionary<string, OutputList[]>`. Then, your entire JSON is just an array of those dictionaries:

```
var instance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, OutputList[]>[]>(json);
```

This gives me a properly deserialized object without any nulls. If it's not the structure you expected or wanted, then you'll need to either change the JSON, change your class structure, or transform the resulting array of dictionaries into e.g. just a single dictionary with multiple key-value pairs:

```
var transformed = instance.SelectMany(o => o)
                          .ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the wonderful explanation.Since I am new to json and c#,could you answer few more queries of mine.

Comment: What will be structure of the classes for the json file I have.I will not be able to change the json file as it a respose from an API.So I need to understand the structure itself.

Comment: public class RootObject
    {
        public UniqueIDs_Values[] ResponseAPI { get; set; }
    }

    public class UniqueIDs_Values
    {
        public Dictionary<string, OutputList> UniqueIDs { get; set; }
    }

Comment: public class OutputList
    {

        public Dictionary<string, FinalValues> GSTIN_Status { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, FinalValues> GSTIN { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, FinalValues> Unique_ID { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, FinalValues> State { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, FinalValues> Input_PAN { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, FinalValues> Processing_Status { get; set; }

    }

Comment: public class FinalValues
    {
        public string GSTIN_Status { get; set; }
        public string GSTIN { get; set; }
        public string Unique_ID { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Input_PAN { get; set; }
        public string Processing_Status { get; set; }
    }

Comment: is this structure okay ? Not able to add all the classes in one comment as character length is exceeding.